# How to access SOAPMessage from within a Spring Aspect in JAX-WS?

Tags: java, web-services, spring, jax-ws

I've got a JAX-WS WebService that is using Spring 3 IOC.  I have coded a Spring Aspect to handle any exceptions and ensure that they are properly handled in the WebService class prior to completing a call.  Within my Aspect, I would like to get access to the user's locale (defined in my SOAP Header), however I am not sure how to do this.

I know I can get the Locale in a handler, but that doesn't help me within my aspect.  I tried injecting the WebServiceContext, but that is always null.

A little digging around pointed me to https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CXF-2674 which seems to indicate that:

1. Spring intentionally does not inject a WebServiceContext object
2. the WebServiceContext is a thin wrapper for the SOAPMessageContext

However, if I try to autowire the SOAPMessageContext instead, that fails as well with the following error message:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private javax.xml.ws.handler.soap.SOAPMessageContext com.cws.cs.lendingsimulationservice.error.ServiceErrorInterceptor.webServiceContext; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set javax.xml.ws.handler.soap.SOAPMessageContext field com.cws.cs.lendingsimulationservice.error.ServiceErrorInterceptor.webServiceContext to java.util.LinkedHashMap
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:502) [spring-beans-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:84) [spring-beans-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:282) [spring-beans-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:]
        ... 21 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set javax.xml.ws.handler.soap.SOAPMessageContext field com.cws.cs.lendingsimulationservice.error.ServiceErrorInterceptor.webServiceContext to java.util.LinkedHashMap
        at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:146) [:1.6.0_29]
        at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:150) [:1.6.0_29]
        at sun.reflect.UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.set(UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.java:63) [:1.6.0_29]
        at java.lang.reflect.Field.set(Field.java:657) [:1.6.0_29]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:498) [spring-beans-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:]
        ... 23 more
```

I figure that there must be a way I can access this information from within an aspect, but cannot seem to figure out how.

If I try to inject a `SOAPMessage` object instead, I get a `org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [javax.xml.soap.SOAPMessage] found for dependency` error message.

Can someone point me in the right direction please?

Thanks,

Eric

Comment: What is your idea behind autowiring `SOAPMessageContext`? On application level it does not exist. It exists only when a message is sent or received, so generally, it needs scoping. IN JAX-WS `SOAPMessageContext` is passed to handler chain: that is the place where you can intersect it and bind to thread local for your aspect.

Comment: I think my concept was misguided, but the idea was that I need access to something in the SOAPHeader at a particular spot in the processing.  To extract it in the endpoint and pass it as a parameter doesn't seem like the right thing, so I wanted to inject the header (and consquently the MessageContext) when I needed the specific information.  When that didn't work, what I ended up doing is extracting the information in a Handler, and setting it in a request-scoped object, that I then inject in the class that requires it.  I had just thought there would be a better solution though.

Comment: I think we are on the same track: `SOAPMessageContext` needs scoping in terms of Spring. If you can post some code as answer to you own question, the community will appreciate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My solution uses a handler and a request-scoped object.  Hopefully someone else might find this useful in the future

Handler:

```
public class ServiceContextHandler implements SOAPHandler<SOAPMessageContext>{

    /**
     * Logger
     */
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ServiceContextHandler.class);

    /**
     * Request object
     */
    @Autowired
    private SOAPHeaderData soapHeaderData;

    /**
     * Ensure that the bean has its parameters injected appropriately
     */
    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        SpringBeanAutowiringSupport.processInjectionBasedOnCurrentContext(this);
    }

    /**
     * Nothing to do on end of message
     */
    public void close(MessageContext context) {
    }


    /**
     * Nothing to do for a fault
     */
    public boolean handleFault(SOAPMessageContext context) {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Process the message
     */
    public boolean handleMessage(SOAPMessageContext context) {
        // no need to bother with outbound requests
        if( !((Boolean) context.get(SOAPMessageContext.MESSAGE_OUTBOUND_PROPERTY)).booleanValue() )
            process(context);
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Doesn't handle any specific QNames in the header
     */
    public Set<QName> getHeaders() {
        return null;
    }


    /**
     * Extract the header parameters
     * @param context
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private void process(SOAPMessageContext context) {
        // Creating the XML tree
        try {
            JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance( ObjectFactory.class);
            Object[] headers = context.getHeaders(new ObjectFactory().createServiceContext(null).getName(), jc, true);

            // find the service context element
            for( Object header : headers ){
                if( (header instanceof JAXBElement<?>) && ((JAXBElement<?>)header).getValue() instanceof ServiceContextType){
                    // found the service context element
                    soapHeaderData.setServiceContext(((JAXBElement<ServiceContextType>)header).getValue());
                    break;
                }
            }

        } catch (JAXBException e) {
            logger.error(ExceptionUtils.getStackTrace(e));
        } catch (WebServiceException e) {
            logger.error(ExceptionUtils.getStackTrace(e));
        }
    }
}
```

Defn of SOAPHeaderData:

```
<!-- SOAPHeaderData -->
<bean id="soapHeaderData" class="com.cws.cs.lendingsimulationservice.header.SOAPHeaderDataImpl" scope="request">
    <aop:scoped-proxy proxy-target-class="false"/>
</bean>
```

where SOAPHeaderDataImpl is a basic POJO (with an interface so as to not need CGLIB).

Hope this helps!  If anything is unclear, let me know.

Thanks,

Eric

Comment: @Dmitry Glad it could be of help.  It took me a while to figure out how to do it all neatly too. :)

Comment: Did you not use @Handlerchain in your webservice to use this handler?

Comment: @Pretty this was so long ago I can't say for sure.  It seems likely configured in a handler. Xml file or something similar.